# Token expiry of Rest Sharp API

Tags: rest, restsharp, rest-client, restcomm

Working on Rest Sharp API automation framework, I have to run a script for 8-10 hrs to do some task. But the token expires after 30 minutes with the message:

> Unauthorized: { "Message":"Expired Token" }

How can I handle it? Or is there any workaround?